# Why is my gas oven tripping the circuit breaker?

Tags: oven, gas

My gas oven is 5 years old. The circuit breaker is brand new. The problem has been happening on and off for the last month.

Comment: Is the new breaker an GCFI/AFCI type with a test button/light?

Comment: Can you please expand on what happened to require the circuit breaker to be replaced?  And was that done by a competent electrician ?   A gas oven doesn't use much electricity compared to an electric one, it only runs the clock and computer and lights, etc.   Please add more details on your oven with [edit]

Comment: Replace the Hot Surface Igniter. If it ain't that then the rats living in there chewed the wires and it's time for a new one anyway.